# Should I self report a bankruptcy for a rental?

Tags: rental-property, bankruptcy

I am looking at a couple of questions on a rental application that I have never been asked before.

One is asking to check off if you ever declared bankruptcy.

What if the bankruptcy was over seven years ago? Should that still be self-reported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, 7 years ago is ever, or? Simple english. They ask if ever, you say it was 7 years ago. So it happend.

Comment: Before your answer, I came to the same conclusion, but it helps to have someone make it explicit. Thanks.